# How to write a binary integer to binary file | c

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite

For example:
If I had this integer 10101011
I want to write 10101011 to binary file in 1 byte

Somthing like this,I thought but **its not working**

```
FILE *f;
int n=10101011;
f=fopen("file","wb");
Fwrite(&n,1,1,f);
```

---

> ***Why you are always does -1 I search and I didnt find something that
>   helped me!!***

---

Comment: I need that in 1 byte @Jayesh

Comment: `10101011` base 10 can't fit inside of a byte.

Comment: @PatrickCollins so I need to convert the binary int to a demical int and then fwrite it?

Comment: @Omer No such thing as a ‘binary int’ or a ‘decimal int’. Sounds like you need to work out what it is that you want to do. If you want to declare an `int` with the *binary* value 0b10101011, use `int n = 171;` or `int n = 0xab`. But mind you, an `int` is larger than a single byte anyway.

Comment: @Biffen so i need to work with char as a number? because char is 1 byte

Comment: @Omer Yes, that'd be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you want to convert a binary to decimal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char c = 0;
    int x = 10101011;
    int rem, i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        rem = x % 10;
        if (rem == 1) {
            c |= 1U << i;
        }
        x /= 10;
    }
    printf("0x%x\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xab
```

Note that you can't use more than 8 digits for `x`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that 10101011 is the binary representation of the integer value you want to write. In that case, you can use an `unsigned char`, since `char` has a size of 1:

```
FILE *f;
unsigned char c = 0xAB; // Equal to the binary number 10101011
f=fopen("file","wb");
fwrite(&c,1,1,f);
```